# React state updating issue when single row has multiple category to select and each category has multiple options

Tags: reactjs, state, use-state

single row-has many categories and categories have multiple radio buttons
i just wanted to push ids as we select options
but state is updating anonymously
so what i did to check if i am doing something wrong

so what i did
i have taken an array
`const [ary,setAry]=useState([])`
whenever we select a option in category
i have passed `onChnage` handler on each input
calling a function

where i do this,

```
console.log(ary)
setAry(...ary,'1')
```

so when there are two categories in single row
if i select one from first category it works fine
but when i select from second category
console returns empty array
i dont know why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

I did it using prevstate
`setState(prevState=>{ return [...prevState,1] }` 
and it worked